# Is there any base representation that produces a non-regular language for set S?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

To clarify, by base representation I mean binary representation (ie. 101 = 5), ternary representation, etc.

Given the set $S$ of natural numbers such that $S = \{2^i| i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ prove that for some base representation of set $S$, the resulting language is not regular.

I have tried but I can't seem to figure out how to prove this. I figure that base 3 would probably result in a nonregular language, but then how would I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in saying that the binary representation of the language is regular because it is defined by the expression $10^*$(regular expression).
You are also right in saying that this does not hold for the ternary representation. 
You can prove the latter in various ways including the "calssic" *pumping lemma* (quite cumbersome in this case) or using ***Cobham's Theorem***.

This theorem says that if you have a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and you take $m,n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that they are *[multiplicatively independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_independence)*, then your set is recognizable by finite automata in both $m$-ary and $n$-ary notation if and only if it is *[ultimately periodic](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Ultimately_periodic_sequence)*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I wanted to try and prove this with the pumping lemma, can you give ma hint as to how I should do this?